# Помогите разобрать массив SQL, PHP, JSON

Tags: php, sql, json

У меня стоит такая задача. Нужно Из таблицы bet_games вытащить записи и взять из поля commission_items значение и потом уже получить по этому параметру запись из таблицы items и далее из items_info. (ПРИМЕР НА КАРТИНКЕ).

Но, есть проблема. В commission_items данные в массиве. Как мне разобрать массив?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно по изображению, мне надо получить данные из таблицы **bet_games** поле **commission_items** затем найти этот полученный параметр в таблице **items**, затем получить **itemd_id** из той же таблице items и уже идти в таблицу **items_info** чтобы получить окончательный результат **price**.

В массиве может быть множество значений [23, 34, 44, 55, 1023]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и зачем надо было json массив писать в базу, создавая себе такие сложности в дальнейшем?

Comment: какая версия mysql ?

Comment: teran, честно признаюсь, писал не я это. Это одного проекта, а я пытаюсь админку написать для него.

Comment: @teran Версия mysql 5.5.58

Comment: а в массиве хранятся данные для столбца `commission_items` ?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев Извините, не совсем понял ваш вопрос. Но, скажу так. В commission_items попадает только то, как в примере выше на картине.  [23, 34, 44, 55, 1023] это id вещей из таблицы items

Comment: *В массиве может быть множество значений [23, 34, 44, 55, 1023]* Покажите именно такую запись.

Comment: @Akina Добавил скрин в посте такой.

Comment: Укажите теперь тип данных поля. Потому как указанная версия MySQL (5.5.58) про существование JSON не знает вообще ничего. Также укажите максимальное количество отдельных значений в таком поле, если подобное ограничение установлено.

Comment: @Akina  commission_items longtext utf8_general_ci NULL

Comment: @Akina на данной версии MYSQL получается никак это не сделать? Только с помощью php возможно?

Comment: То есть ограничения на количество итемов в поле - не существует? тогда только хранимая процедура, запросом задача не решается. Нормализуете ваш массив итемов во временную таблицу (один итем на запись, плюс id записи из исходной таблицы) и используете её в запросе.

Comment: @Akina да ограничения не существует. Эх, как всё сложно(

Comment: А такой вариант не сработает ` SELECT 
      ii.price FROM items AS i        
    INNER JOIN 
      items_info AS ii ON i.item_id = ii.id
    WHERE 
      i.id in(
       (
         select SUBSTR(bg.commission_items, 1, (LENGTH(bg.commission_items)-1)) 
         from bet_games AS bg where bg.id = 2835
       )
      )`

Comment: Чтобы сработал вариант вхождения по подстроке - удалите обрамляющие скобки и используйте FIND_IN_SET(). Но работать будет медленно и печально...

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк).

Comment: @Akina сейчас попробую догнать про FIND_IN_SET()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можете еще сделать так:

сначала делаете запрос в таблицу `bet_games` по `id` получаете нужную    вам запись.

Из данной записи получаете столбец `commission_items` с    помощью `json_decode` получаем массив

После массив переводим в строку (пример строки "23, 34, 44, 55, 1023")

Добавляем данную строку в sql запрос :

```
SELECT
ii.price FROM items AS i        
INNER JOIN 
items_info AS ii ON i.item_id = ii.id
WHERE i.id IN($stringID)
```